# Customize page info when using crop package

Tags: packages, crop

By default the package "crop" adds not only crop marks to the pages of the document, but also a line with some information about the page/document, i.e. filename, date, time, pagenumber. I would like to customize this information, e.g. add a note to myself. Can I accomplish that without changing the package? If so, how?

Comment: Newer versions of `geometry` provide cropmarks, you might want to check their customization possibilities, too (I haven't, so I don't know what is easy/possible there).

Comment: @mbork: I was not aware of that feature of geometry, thanks for pointing me to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine the internal macro `\CROP@@info` which prints that information. It's mentioned in the implementation section of the `crop` documentation.

More general and independent of the implementation: you could call the `\cropdef` command. Its first and optional argument is the macro which provides the page info (default: `\CROP@@info`). Four further arguments stand for macros for the corners. It's described in section *2.7 Defining your own marks* in the `crop` manual.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, first I was a bit afraid by the many things that happen in \CROP@@info which I don't fully understand, but in the end I found the place where to add my note. In fact I just copied the whole definition from crop.sty and added a line in between.